# i want to show image, when button is clicked. please let me know, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to show imageView, when button is clicked. using layout property ; visibility and alignParentBottom.

i expected :

[image]

But it doesn't work. I have no idea.

Please check my code.

just simply button and imageView added in activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="show"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:visibility="gone"

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

result here : 
[image]

So how to fix this problem ?

please give me some tips.

Comment: Try setting the gravity of the image view and button to bottom maybe? Is the first picture you have up top the way you want it unclicked and clicked. Then the picture at the bottom is the one you have yourself unclicked and clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your XML file as:
Java file will remian the same

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="show"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:visibility="gone"

    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it works! using LinearLayout - orientation and, gravitiy? i will search this. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to align your ImageView bottom in Parent by adding `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` , and set your button above it : `android:layout_above="@+id/imageView"`, this will work

Comment: you mean this? android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and this android:layout_above="@+id/imageView" right?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="show"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:visibility="gone"

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```